# windows 10 Yarn install throws error, not able to fix

Tags: node.js, windows, npm-install, yarnpkg

when i do `yarn install` i am getting following error. not able to understand. number time i have reinstalled the node. but nothing works. any one help to understand the real help and fix?

here is the details:

```
Arguments: 
  C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\jbari\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js install

PATH: 
  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.13\bin;F:\sonar\sonar-scanner-4.6.2.2472-windows\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\jbari\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\jbari\AppData\Local\Volta\bin;C:\Users\jbari\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\jbari\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\jbari\AppData\Roaming\npm

Yarn version: 
  1.22.17

Node version: 
  16.13.1

Platform: 
  win32 x64

Trace: 
  Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, scandir 'C:\Users\jbari\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v6\npm-core-util-is-1.0.2-b5fd54220aa2bc5ab57aab7140c940754503c1a7-integrity\node_modules\core-util-is'
```

if I try with npm getting the following error:

```
119 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
120 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\jbari\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
121 verbose node v16.13.1
122 verbose npm  v8.3.0
123 error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
124 verbose exit 1
```